# How to change data in Django ModelForm?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

models.py

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    num_of_songs = models.IntegerField(max_length=15)
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
    songs = models.ManyToManyField("Song", blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
class PlaylistEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Playlist
        fields = ['name', 'songs']
```

I calculate `duration` and `num_of_songs` based on the songs I get from the form. But I do that calculation from a view.

views.py

```
playlist = Playlist.objects.get(id=playlist_id)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PlaylistEditForm(request.POST, instance=playlist)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        playlist.duration = playlist.songs.aggregate(Sum('duration'))['duration__sum'] or 0
        playlist.num_of_songs = playlist.songs.count()
        playlist.save()
```

I want to calculate `duration` and `num_of_songs` inside a form.

Comment: you can move the calculation to the form overriding its `.save` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can move the calculation to the form overriding the form's `save` method

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    instance = super(PlaylistEditForm, self).save(commit=False)
    instance.duration = instance.songs.aggregate(Sum('duration'))['duration__sum'] or 0
    instance.num_of_songs = instance.songs.count()
    if commit:
        instance.save()
    return instance
```

and your view becomes

```
playlist = Playlist.objects.get(id=playlist_id)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PlaylistEditForm(request.POST, instance=playlist)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```

Please refer to Django's [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) for further info.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason not to do it in the models `save()` method? If you have it in the forms save() method, the duration and num_of_songs in the database will not get updated if you save the model instance other than from the modelform.

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    num_of_songs = models.IntegerField(max_length=15)
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
    songs = models.ManyToManyField("Song", blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk:
            self.duration = self.songs.aggregate(Sum('duration'))['duration__sum'] or 0
            self.num_of_songs = self.songs.count()
        return super(Playlist, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

You view would be:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PlaylistEditForm(request.POST, instance=playlist)
    if form.is_valid():
        playlist = form.save()
```

Comment: You brought up a good issue. I tried this, but it didn't work. The problem with your save method is that it tries to read data from the database. Let's say I'm creating a new playlist object from django admin page. How can it call aggregate and count methods on an non-existent object in the database? That's why I'm changing the form save method, now I need to import that form to django ModelAdmin. Unless I'm mistaken and you know of a better way please let me know.

Comment: You are right. I added ```if self.pk``` which checks if the object exists. But this is not ideal. Another possibility would be using djangos ```post_save signal``` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#post-save